# Convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n(n+2)7}{\sqrt[4](n!)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series is convergent or divergent: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n(n+2)7}{\sqrt[4](n!)}$

**Prove by using** the **direct comparison test**, or the **limit comparison test**.

What I got until now is the following: At first it seems like a sum that should converge, but no idea how to prove it.

I noticed I can take out 7 from the fraction and by the "laws of Sums" without changing its convergence. Moreover, I tried to separate the Sum into two Sums: $\frac{n*3^n}{\sqrt[4](n!)}$ and $\frac{2*3^n}{\sqrt[4](n!)}$ and to prove individually for each of them the convergence. but again without any success.

would appreciate your guidance and help

Comment: +1 Did you try ratio test?

Comment: actually I'm not allowed to use the ratio test..

Comment: I didn't read well, but here is the thing. Use the ratio test to see if you can an answer. If you know the answer to your series, than at least that might be helpful to establish an answer using one of the methods you mentioned.

Comment: Hmmmm. So are you aware that $n!$ ultimately grows faster than any exponential growth?

Comment: @Vim yes I'm aware but I'm not sure how to use this knowledge. I used the ratio test as imranfat adviced and found out both parts of the sum are convergent. but yet no clue how to establish out of that an answer by the comparison tests..

Comment: The ratio test works immediately and I honestly can't see how the comparison tests can work here, and I also don't understand why would anyone want to give up the ratio test unless there's something interesting to learn from the comparison ones .Interesting to see some answer.

Comment: Use Stirling approximation for $n!$.

Comment: @imranfat I used the ratio test as adviced and found out both parts of sums are convergent. but yet no clue how to establish out of that an answer by the comparison tests..

Answer (score 1):

If you choose $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ to compare with then

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{a_n} {b_n} =0$$

by limit comparison test. So your series $\sum_n a_n$ converges.

Comment: Ah, that's nice

Comment: @imranfat  can you pls explain me following:-

(1) how you come up with $1/n^2 $ ? why not other
(2)how to calculate limit?
my atttempt:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n (n+2) 7 n^2}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{4}}} \rightarrow$ how to deal with factorial part. 
Kindly clarify. I am beginner and going thru some posts